# Problem with rebuild solution - no assembly reference

Tags: asp.net-core, reference

I tried rebuild my solutions (added new projects, subfolders etc.). But when I compiled my solution I get some issue from views files "The "CategoryModel" type or namespace does not exist in the "Application.ViewModels" namespace (is there an assembly reference missing?". I created project Application with ViewModels and added file - CategoryModel. But I can't reference to them. Why?

```cs
   @model Application.ViewModels.CategoryModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dodaj nową kategorię";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var SubcategoriesData = (IList<Application.ViewModels.SubcategoryModel>)ViewBag.Subcategories;
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

My CategoryModel class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccessLogic.Entities
{
    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubcategoryModel> Subcategories {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with the code in the `CategoryModel.cs` file  in Application project for reference.

Comment: Ok, I have got bad namespace :) DataAccessLogic.Entities was wrong. When I copied forgot about them...